# realtime search with angularJS

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete, real-time

I use that code (Angular JS + ngautocomplete)

```
<div ng-controller="autocomplete_cities">
            <form id="form" role="form">
                <div class="form-group move-down">
                    <label for="Autocomplete">Autocomplete - Cities in Canada</label>
                    <input type="text" id="Autocomplete" class="form-control" ng-autocomplete ng-model="result2" details="details2" options="options2"/>
                </div>
                <div>result: {{result2}}</div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

This code is for user search à city with an googlemaps autocomplete system. (script works)
I'v make an ajax script that request all entries where city is `$result2` (script works).

**My problem:** I would like that ajax's script run everytime user press enter or select an autocomplete suggestions. Like onchange `{{result2}} = execute ajax.`

Comment: Have you looked into `ng-change`?

Comment: Yes but I don't know where insert ng-change for this problem.

Comment: Try adding it to the `<input>`, so when the input changes it calls a function which performs a new search and updates the view.